# Pacemaker with scsi fence device

Tags: cluster, iscsi

I'm trying to setup a 3x nodes cluster with corosync and pacemaker, with scsi fencing.

I do not know why the cluster status says there's no fencing device, while the fencing device is actually there:

```
$ sudo pcs status
Cluster name: nfs_cluster

WARNINGS:
No stonith devices and stonith-enabled is not false

Cluster Summary:
  * Stack: corosync
  * Current DC: nfs1.urbaman.it (version 2.1.2-ada5c3b36e2) - partition with quorum
  * Last updated: Mon Aug 21 14:52:04 2023
  * Last change:  Mon Aug 21 14:50:40 2023 by root via cibadmin on nfs1.urbaman.it
  * 3 nodes configured
  * 3 resource instances configured

Node List:
  * Online: [ nfs1.urbaman.it nfs2.urbaman.it nfs3.urbaman.it ]

Full List of Resources:
  * Resource Group: nfs_group:
    * nfs_server        (systemd:nfs-server):    Started nfs1.urbaman.it
    * nfs_ip    (ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2):         Started nfs1.urbaman.it
    * scsi-shooter      (stonith:fence_scsi):    Started nfs1.urbaman.it

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/disabled
  pacemaker: active/disabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

More than that, the fencing seems to work (the fenced node gets off), but the node do not reboot, I have to manually restart the cluster on the node.

Is there a way to properly set the scsi fencing device?

PS: At the moment, the scsi shared disk is not a raw device, it has a 100% partition on:

```
$ sudo ls /dev/disk/by-id | grep wwn
wwn-0x600140588e28679158549bf8bc7aa9eb
wwn-0x600140588e28679158549bf8bc7aa9eb-part1
```

Could it be the problem? EDIT: no, even without the partition, the cluster seems not to recognize the fencing device, the fencing device being there, and the fenced node do not reboot.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 22.04, both on cluster nodes and on iscsi target

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved eliminatind the scsi device and made it working with a software watchdog and a diskless sbd.

Now fwncing properly works, and nodes also restart.